# How to sum the length of particular array field present in all objects inside an array in mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

This is the sample of my mongodb document( try to use jsonformatter.com to analyse it):

```
{"_id":"6278686","playerName":"Rohit Lal","tournamentId":"197831","score":[{"_id":"1611380","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":0,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"-","catches":["Mohit Mishra"],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1602732","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":0,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"-","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1536514","runsScored":1,"ballFaced":3,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":33.33,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"run out Sameer Baveja","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1536474","runsScored":2,"ballFaced":7,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":28.57,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"c Rajesh b Prasad Naik","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1536467","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":0,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"-","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1500825","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":0,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"-","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1461428","runsScored":18,"ballFaced":6,"fours":1,"sixes":2,"strikeRate":300,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"not out","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1461408","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":1,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"c Sudhir b Vinay Kasat *vk*","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1451175","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":0,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"-","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1451146","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":0,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"-","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]},{"_id":"1392796","runsScored":0,"ballFaced":1,"fours":0,"sixes":0,"strikeRate":0,"oversBowled":0,"runsConceded":0,"economyRate":0,"wickets":0,"maiden":0,"howToOut":"c †Vinay Kedia b Lalit","catches":[],"stumping":[],"runout":[],"participatedRunout":[]}],"__v":0}
```

I want to sum the length of catches array field of all objects inside score array. I know, I can achieve it using aggregation framework, but I am begineer in mongodb and does not have knowledge of many aggregation operators. Here is the aggregation pipeline I have tried but it returns the number of existence of this field, not the sum of length of this array:

```
[
    "totalCatches": {
        $size: "$score.catches"
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Descontruct `score` array field to multiple documents.
2. `$group` - Group by `null` (for all objects), next `$sum` for the `$size` of `score.catches`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$score"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      "totalCatches": {
        $sum: {
          $size: "$score.catches"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p1An60OUyOA)

---

**Note**: If you want the result to be based on each document (not combine all documents), then you need to change the `$group`'s _id as:

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      ...
   }   
}
```